# How to make a Web/Http server running on Windows 7 accessible within the same network?

Tags: networking, windows-services, firewall, group-policy

I have a Web server running on a Windows 7 in a company domain. Although it sounds like it should work out of the box, but so far I can't access the web server within the same network(home) with a browser. I can't `telnet` access it either(timeout error), I can only `ping` it. I tried accessing it by its IP assigned by my home router's DHCP. I also tried using its full computer name.

I though something must be wrong with the firewall settings. So I tried enabling it, disabling it, I tried adding a new rule with a port the server is using, but nothing works!

On the other hand, if I put the Web Server on a Linux machine and access it from the Windows 7 machine, everything works. So there must be something wrong with the Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a Trend Micro security software installed on the Windows 7 machine, and it has a lot of firewall rules defined there that I can't touch. So dead end...

[image]